# ActionView::Template::Error (Unexpected character '#' deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

For some reason, all of a sudden, I can't view my site via Heroku. I get this error

```
   ActionView::Template::Error (Unexpected character '#' (line: 23168, col: 1, pos: 699588)
```

All research has pointed to my application.js having something going on in there, the file is large so would be unfair to put it on here, unless anyone needs to see it? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

So after some more research I had to compile the assets locally before deployment, which i have never had to do before, very strange

```
 bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: Could it be that whatever gem you are using to compile the JS on heroku is different than what you use locally during development? Maybe you have an open-ended gem version (e.g. gem 'compiler', '> 3.0') and heroku is using one that's different somehow?